# Which protobuf version should I build?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, protocol-buffers

I'm missing libprotobuf.so.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to install Protobuf 3.0.0 but got libprotobuf.so.10, built Protobuf 2.5.0 but got libprotobuf.so.8.

I don't want to continue randomly building Protobuf versions to find out which produces libprotobuf.so.7 and I can't find anywhere where it says which is the right version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build **Protobuf 2.4.1** version. After building this version it will create **libprotobuf.so.7**  .